# How to retrieve variable (like count) with Selenium from XPATH

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I am trying to **scrape** the like count of an instagram post using selenium/python.
How can I locate the like count using xpath and save the count into a variable?

This is the section where the count of likes is being shown:

```
<section class="EDfFK ygqzn">
    <div class="                     Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_     ybXk5   vwCYk                                                                                                               ">
        <div class="                     Igw0E _56XdI          eGOV_         _4EzTm                                       ItkAi                                                                       ">
            <a class="zV_Nj" href="/p/asd123asd123asd123ads123asd123asd123/liked_by/" tabindex="0">
                <div class="                     Igw0E   rBNOH         hLiUi    ybXk5    _4EzTm                                                                                                              ">
                    <div style="height: 20px; width: 20px; order: 0;" class="KcRNL mOBkM    ">
                        <span class="_2dbep " role="link" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" tabindex="-1">
                            <img alt="testguys Profilbild" class="_6q-tv" crossorigin="anonymous" data-testid="user-avatar" draggable="false" src="https://scontent-vie1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t99.9999-99/s150x150/9999999_9999999_9999999_n.jpg?tp=1&amp;_nc_ht=scontent-vie1-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_ohc=123asd123asd123asd123asd&amp;ccb=7-4&amp;oh=123asd123asd123asd123asd&amp;oe=608D16CE&amp;_nc_sid=asd123"</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="Nm9Fw">Gefällt
            <span class="Jv7Aj mArmR MqpiF  ">
                <a class="FPmhX notranslate  cqXBL" title="testguy" href="/testguy/" tabindex="0">testguy</a>
            </span>
            und
            <a class="zV_Nj" href="/p/qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbn/liked_by/" tabindex="0">
                <span>63</span>
                weitere Personen
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

In this case, the like count should be "63".
I tried to copy the Xpath out of Firefox within the dev tools and utilize this:

```
post_like_count = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[2]/div/div[2]/a/span")
```

But that did not work due to ".NoSuchElementException".
Do I have to add a variable into the xpath above?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I would think `//a[@class='zV_Nj'/span` would do it.

Comment: ```post_like_count = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='zV_Nj'/span") ``` is not a legal expression according to selenium.

Comment: Try `post_like_count = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='zV_Nj']/span")` -- I added the missing close bracket.

Comment: Are you trying to get the "Likes" count for a post by a specific user? A specific post?

Comment: Error: Unable to locate element: //a[@class='zV_Nj']/span

Comment: @GregBurghardt I want to count the likes for every single post of any user.

Comment: Ok. So you are just going down the page, post by post, and counting likes?

Comment: @GregBurghardt correct. Eventually I want to count the number of likes and number of comments.

Comment: The CSS classes are all munged. Are the CSS classes consistent with each page view, or do the CSS classes change?

Comment: better show URL to this page - and then we can test code on real data. Server may send different data for different requests.

Comment: Please provide enough wait before interacting the element. Check this link [ExplicitWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: maybe page uses JavaScript to add elements and it needs some `time.sleep()` (or  [Selenium Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)) to wait for data in web browser ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `contains`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "%s")]' % "liked_by")
```

Comment: Results in an error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: liked_by

Comment: Error: Unable to locate element: //a[contains(@href, "liked_by")]

Comment: @sgtwagner123 Do you have synchronisations handled in your code? You have to wait till the element is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't use xpath like this in professional manner:

`post_like_count = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[2]/div/div[2]/a/span")`

Because this notation is static. When any changes happen in the web page, this address could be invalid, and your all code may be corrupted.

So, I suggest you to use like this for this situation and along with other use cases of yours.

As I understand it, you wanted the obtain "63". There is no way to tell something certain from this point of view but this might work well for you:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='Nm9Fw']/a[@class='Nm9Fw']/span/text()")`